# Django/DjangoRestFramework, Serializers: return user's data plus one more json in one response

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I'm using `django rest-framework` in `python 3.5`.

When `User.objects.filter(uid = data['id']).exists()` I want to combine user's data and `{"isnew":"TRUE"}` in one json string and return it as response.

User's data have this structure:

I have the following view function.

```
class UserRegister(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    serializer_class = RegisterUserSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = RegisterUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        # Check format and unique constraint
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, \
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        data = serializer.data


        if User.objects.filter(uid = data['id']).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(uid = data['id'])
            json_resp = { "user":JsonResponse(user), "isnew":"TRUE"}

            return Response(json_resp, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        else:
            u = User.objects.create(uid=data['id'], firstname=data['firstname'], yearofbirth=data['yearofbirth'], \
                                    lastname=data['lastname'], othernames=data['othernames'])
            u.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Then I get the error `TypeError: <User: User object> is not JSON serializable`.

The ideal response must be something like:

```
{
user: {
    "user_id": "844822",
    "firstname": "zinonas",
    "yearofbirth": 1984,
    "lastname": "",
    "othernames": ""
}, 
isnew: "false"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just after the condition `if User.objects.filter(uid = data['id']).exists()` contains lines:

```
user = User.objects.get(uid = data['id'])
json_resp = { "user":JsonResponse(user), "isnew":"TRUE"}
```

These lines in which you are calling { "user": JsonResponse(user) }, you are serializing a user object to JSON and hence the error that has been raised. Solution is to convert user object into a json serializable datatype, probably by implementing a to_dict() method in user model, or you can simply do `json_resp = {"user": user.__dict__, "isnew": "TRUE"}` i.e. use `__dict__`.

PS: Data serialization step should always be performed in serializer and hence writing this entire piece of code should always be preferred in serializer. You could have override your `to_representation` function in serializer. You could have also written an additional `read_only` `SerializerMethodField`, any method that you might have seen fit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the dictionary first before serializing it:

```
json_resp = {'user': User.objects.get(uid = data['id']).values()[0]}
json_resp['isnew'] = "TRUE"

return Jsonresponse(json_resp, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the RegisterUserSerializer, you can add custom fields using serializerMethodfield and attach the boolean field according to your logic. Please refer this:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield